# Find a font by tag

Tags: fonts

This is not a "what font is this" question, but rather a question about how to search for fonts.

I usually have an idea of what I want the font to convey, but have trouble finding a font corresponding to the feeling I want. Dafont's classification is really helpful, but I wondered if there was a place with something "more".

For example, let's say I want a font "sober", "light", or "young", or even a combination of these. Is there a place where fonts would be sorted like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DAFONT's ratio of good-to-awful fonts is something like 1:100. It's not the place to go to browse typefaces most of the time.

Your best bet is likely myfonts.com

They represent a rather huge variety of type designers and vendors and have a fairy extensive tagging/classification system that makes it fairly easy to navigate around by style/theme/etc.

All that said, not sure 'sober' and 'young' would be terms often used to describe typefaces, so that still may be a bit of a challenge.

Comment: **sober** is obviously the opposite of italic, **young** is the opposite of bold and **light** is the opposite of regular. In some cases **light** may refer to the opposite of bold as well... or so I've heard...

Comment: This is another Crushed Peony Boogers nomenclature issue. "Sober" to me would mean "subdued, elegant, and corporate": Bank Gothic, Bodoni, Adobe Garamond. You can have Bodoni italic and AGaramond italic. "Italic" doesn't mean "drunk and thereby falling over." Similarly, "young" is "fun, silly, playful" like Lemonade or Paisley or Fajita, any of which could be bold.

Comment: Yes, I was referring more to the feeling "subdued, elegant, and corporate" rather than "not italic", else... I would just have looked for "not italic" ;)